# SQL procedure sum and sum inside select and insert to

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a little problem. I have a **insert into** block with **select** and inside select I have **sum**. Thats works well. But In this select I need also do some operation on these **sums**. I don't know how.
Code:

```
insert into [dbo].[DiscountDailyStatsTemp]
    SELECT
        @DiscountId, 
        cast([dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventTime] as date) as 'Date', 
        sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountLike' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Likes',
        sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountDislike' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Dis likes',
        sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountShare' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Shares',
        SUM(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName]='DiscountView' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Views',
        SUM(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName]='DiscountClick' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Clicks', 
        Sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountCode' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Downloaded codes',
        Sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountSave' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Saves',
        sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountClickWWW' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Page redirections',
        0 as 'Average CTR',
        @UniqueUsers as 'Unique users',
        @NewUsers as 'New users',
        @ReturningUsers as 'Returning users',
        Sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountCommentPositive' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Positive comments',
        sum(case when [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountCommentNegative' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Negative comments'
    from [dbo].[TelemetryData] 
    where [dbo].[TelemetryData].[DiscountId] = @DiscountId
        and ([dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountView' or [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountClick' or 
        [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountDislike' or [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountCode' or 
        [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountLike' or [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountShare' or
        [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountClickWWW' or [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountSave' or
        [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountCommentPositive' or [dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventName] = 'DiscountCommentNegative')
    group by cast([dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventTime] as date)
    order by cast([dbo].[TelemetryData].[EventTime] as date) asc
```

And look there is **0 as 'Average CTR'** I need to change it for this:

```
Round(cast('Clicks' as float) / cast(case when 'Views' = 0 then 1 else 'Views') end as float) * 100, 2) as 'Average CTR',
```

But it not working. How I can do it?

Comment: "Not working" is not a problem description. I would think your problem is `cast('Clicks' as float)`, what are you trying to do there? You can't cast a string to a float.

Comment: I mean that 'Clicks' should be Sum of 'Clicks' in this select.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the aliases in the same level they are created, and also this is a query with a group by clause, which means each column should be either in the group by or with an aggregation function around it.

You can wrap your query with another select :

```
SELECT [date],
       [likes],
       ....
       Round(cast([Clicks] as float) / cast(case when [Views] = 0 then 1 else [Views] end) as float) * 100, 2) as [Average CTR],
FROM(YOUR QUERY HERE)
```

Also, use square brackets for columns name.

Comment: Sagi How can this work? `'Views'` is a string. Fieldnames on tsql need brackets`[]`. And a `CASE` cant return integer/string

Comment: @Nerf Like I said before, "Not working" is not a problem description. How are we supposed to know that list of values is incorrect?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It's a typo.. I changed any single quotes instead of this one.. I also told the OP to use square brackets ..